# Handle unsuccessful Ajax calls with Redux and Redux Thunk in React

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-redux

For my React components, I use Redux (react-redux) and Redux Thunk to maintain the app state.

There's a `ShowGroup` component that retrieves a `group` from the backend. If the group doesn't exist (or in any other error situation), an error callback is called to update the state.

```
class ShowGroup extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.groupId = this.props.match.params.id;
    this.state = {
      'loaded': false,
      'error': null
    };
  }

  _fetchGroupErrorCallback = response => {
    this.setState({loaded: true, error: response});
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    this.props.fetchGroup(this.groupId, this._fetchGroupErrorCallback);
  }

  render() {
    //what is the best practice here ?
    let group = this.props.groups[this.groupId];
    if (!group) {
      if (!this.state.loaded) {
        return <div>Loading group ....</div>;
      }
      if (this.state.error) {
        return <div>{this.state.error.data.message}</div>;
      }
    }
    return (
      <div className="show-group">
        <form>
          {_.map(FIELDS, renderField.bind(this))}
        </form>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

function mapStateToProps(state) {
  return { groups: state.groups };
}

const mapDispatchToProps = (dispatch) => {
    return {
        fetchGroup: (id, callback) => dispatch(fetchGroup(id, callback)),
        updateGroup: (id) => dispatch(updateGroup(id))
    };
};

export default reduxForm({
  validate,
  //a unique id for this form
  form:'ShowGroup',
  fields: _.keys(FIELDS),
  fields_def: FIELDS
})(
  connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps)(ShowGroup)
);
```

(it's a `redux-form` component that doesn't matter)

```
export function fetchGroup(id, fetchErrorCallback) {
  return (dispatch) => {
    axios.get(URL, AUTHORIZATION_HEADER)
      .then(response => {
        dispatch(groupFetched(response))
      })
      .catch(({response}) => {
        fetchErrorCallback(response);
        dispatch(groupFetchErrored(response));
      })
  };
}
```

`groupFetchedErrored` action creator:

```
export function groupFetchErrored(response) {
  //handle the error here
  return {
     type: FETCH_GROUP_ERROR,
     response
  }
}
```

And the reducer:

```
export default function(state=INITIAL_STATE, action) {
  switch(action.type) {
    //....
    case FETCH_GROUP_ERROR:
      return _.omit(state, action.response.data.id);
    default:
      return state;
  }
}
```

**The problem:**

**A.** In case of an error response, the component gets rendered three times:
1. First time it loads (which after the ajax call is made)
2. `_fetchGroupErrorCallback` is called and the state is set, which leads to a render
3. `groupFetchErrored` is dispatched which leads to another render

**B.** In case of successful response, the component gets rendered twice, BUT the state is not correct as nothing updates it (and I don't think it's correct to add a callback for it)

What is the best practice for handling ajax error responses when using Redux and Redux-Thunk with React ? How should the action creator and reducer notify the component that there's something wrong ?

**Update 1**

This is my root reducer:

```
const rootReducer = combineReducers({
  form: formReducer,
  groups: groupReducer
});

export default rootReducer;
```

As you can see, I have `groups` which is an object of form:

```
{
   groupId1: groupData1,
   groupId2, groupData2, 
   ....
}
```

So, another question is, how should I specify one group is loading (I cannot have `isLoading` or `errorFetching` on the `groups` level, and it doesn't seem to be a good idea to add one entry for each invalid group id user may try. Or maybe there's a way to put the invalid group id in the map and then clean it up ? I don't know where should that happen, though.

Comment: Why are you using both state and props? Make props the single source of truth and don't use state at all.

Comment: That sounds good, but how should `fetchGroup` tell the component that server responded with an error ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Put all state data related to the fetch into the Redux store. Then the store becomes your single source of truth.

You can then omit `fetchErrorCallback` entirely.

You already have a place in your reducer that's being notified of the error:

```
case FETCH_GROUP_ERROR:
  return _.omit(state, action.response.data.id);
```

You can store the error in the redux state right there:

```
case FETCH_GROUP_ERROR:
  const stateWithoutId = _.omit(state, action.response.data.id);
  return {
    ...stateWithoutId,
    errorFetching: action.response.error,
    isLoading: false
  }
```

Then pass `errorFetching` and `isLoading` in to your component via `mapStateToProps` like you're already doing with `groups`.

Also to properly track `isLoading` it would be best to dispatch another action when you start the fetch (right before the call to `axios.get`), perhaps `FETCH_GROUP_STARTED`. Then in your reducer set it `isLoading` to `true` when that action type is dispatched.

```
case GROUP_FETCHED: 
  return { 
    ...state, 
    isLoading: false,
    group: action.response.data // or however you're doing this now.

  };
case FETCH_GROUP_STARTED:
  return { ...state, isLoading: true }; // or maybe isFetchingGroups is a better name
```

If this were my code I'd make another change: Instead of passing `response` in to the action creators, I'd strip out just the relevant data and pass *that* to them. So the reducer doesn't need to know how to handle a `response` object; it just receives the data that is needed to display your component(s) correctly. That way all the code that handles axios calls and has to know about the shape of the objects they return is in one place - the action function. Something like:

### Action creators

```
export function groupFetchErrored(errorWithId) {
  return {
     type: FETCH_GROUP_ERROR,
     payload: errorWithId
  }
}

export function groupFetchSucceeded(groupData) 
  return {
     type: GROUP_FETCHED,
     payload: groupData
  }
}
```

### Action

```
export function fetchGroup(id, fetchErrorCallback) {
  return (dispatch) => {
    axios.get(URL, AUTHORIZATION_HEADER)
      .then(response => {
        dispatch(groupFetched(response.data)) // or whatever chunk you need out of response
      })
      .catch(({response}) => {
        dispatch(groupFetchErrored({
            error: response.error, 
            id: response.data.id
          }
        );
      })
  };
}
```

### Reducer

You may have noticed I used `action.payload` in the action creators above.

It's a common practice to always use the same name for the data property on dispatched actions (like always, in every reducer and every action creator across the entire app). That way your reducer doesn't need to be tightly coupled to the action creator; it knows the data is always going to be in the `payload` field. (Maybe that's what you were doing with `response`, but that seems like it's intended to be used specifically for http responses.)

```
case GROUP_FETCHED: 
  return { 
    ...state, 
    isLoading: false,
    group: action.payload
  };
case FETCH_GROUP_STARTED:
  return { ...state, isLoading: true }; // no payload needed
case FETCH_GROUP_ERROR:
  const dataId = action.payload.id;
  const stateWithoutId = _.omit(state, dataId);
  return {
    ...stateWithoutId,
    errorFetching: action.payload.error,
    isLoading: false
  }
```

Comment: The first time that the component renders, there's no `isLoading` or `errorFetching`, how should these values be initialized ?

Comment: and I think you meant to dispatch `groupFetchSucceeded` in the Action, right ? because there would be no groupFetched anymore.

Comment: You could initialize isLoading and errorFetching in the reducer, but that would be more for documentation purposes. Since they've never been set they will both be `undefined` which evaluates to false.

Comment: I used initial state in the reducer, and it works right. 
I added Update 1 to my question, which is kind of a state design question. I would appreciate if you could take a look (and it's related to the design you suggested)

Comment: Regarding handling fetches of multiple different groups, that's a big topic. Ultimately you want your redux state to hold everything the UI needs to show the user what's happening. People have done that many different ways. You could store arrays in your reducer. I suggest starting a new question for that topic - but search first because it's a common problem.

Answer (score 0):

In the new template and documentation for redux, you can use the extraReducers, and check the pending/fulfilled status of the thunk action.
It is much simpler, and will render your component only once.
For example:

```
export const load = createAsyncThunk(
  'worldtime/load',
  async (arg, thunkApi) => {
    const {ok, response} = await sendRequest('get', '/api/json/est/now')

    if (ok) {
      return response
    }
  },
)
```

and then the extraReducers can check the payload:

```
.addCase(load.fulfilled, (state, action) => {
  state.loading = false
  if (!action.payload) {
    // request had failed, do not update
    return
  }
  state.queries++
  state.time = action.payload.currentDateTime
})
```